# Auto Scroll en Tabla con HTML y JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy haciendo una tabla con un auto scroll, pero no he logrado que funcione, solo con el scroll que el navegado provee, pero con el scroll que contiene la tabla no funciona y es el que necesito en este momento.

Esta es la tabla:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="clock.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
    tr:nth-child(even)  {
   background-color:#272727dd; border: 0px solid #000;
}
</style>
<body style="background-color: #000;">
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"><label style="font-size: 30px; color: #d1d1d1;">Clasificación</label></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                        <div class="clock">
                            <div class="display"></div>
                            <div class="display2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="table-responsive mt-3">
                <table class="table" style="color: #fff; border: 0px solid #000;" id="tblNeedsScrolling">
                    <thead class="estatico" style="background-color: #131313dd; color: #ffffff; border: 0px solid #000; text-align: center;">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Columna 1</th>
                            <th>Columna 2</th>
                            <th>Columna 3</th>
                            <th>Columna 4</th>
                            <th>Estatus</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>texto 1</td><td>texto 2</td><td>texto 3</td><td>texto 4</td><td class="text-center"><i class="badge" style="font-size:15px; background-color: #7e0000; color: #000;">Finalizado</i></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>texto 1</td><td>texto 2</td><td>texto 3</td><td>texto 4</td><td class="text-center"><i class="badge" style="font-size:15px; background-color: #fff700; color: #000;">En proceso</i></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>texto 1</td><td>texto 2</td><td>texto 3</td><td>texto 4</td><td class="text-center"><i class="badge" style="font-size:15px; background-color: #38a900; color: #000;">En espera</i></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>texto 1</td><td>texto 2</td><td>texto 3</td><td>texto 4</td><td class="text-center"><i class="badge" style="font-size:15px; background-color: #38a900; color: #000;">En espera</i></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>texto 1</td><td>texto 2</td><td>texto 3</td><td>texto 4</td><td class="text-center"><i class="badge" style="font-size:15px; background-color: #7e0000; color: #000;">Finalizado</i></td></tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Así es como se visualiza la tabla, y lo marcado es el scroll que quiero que funcione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Este es el codigo que use con el scroll del navegador y si es funcional.

```
setTimeout(pageScroll,3000);
    const MARGEN = .1;
    function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,40);
        scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll,3000);
        if(MARGEN > $(document).height() - $(window).scrollTop() - $(window).height()) {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            //Ajax
        }
    }
```

2. Este es el código JavaScript que he intentado para darle funcionamiento al scroll de la Tabla pero no ha funcionado.

```
    var el = $(".table-responsive");
    setTimeout(pageScroll,3000);
    const MARGEN = .1;
    function pageScroll() {
      alert(el)
      var st = el.scrollTop();
      var sb = el.prop("scrollHeight")-el.innerHeight();
      el.animate({scrollTop: st<sb/2 ? sb : 0}, 4000, pageScroll);
  
      scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll,3000);
    }
```

No se si alguno me pudiera ayudar a solucionar el auto scroll de la tabla.

Comment: Quita los paréntesis de `innerHeight`, porque es una propiedad y no un método.

Comment: aun así sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Considera la posibilidad de controlar usando la propiedad [overflow](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#propdef-overflow) es posible que funcione aplicado a tbody (nunca lo he usado con tablas pero en la documentación dice que aplica a los elementos que aceptan modelo de bloque).

Comment: gracias @quevedo , revisare la documentación

Answer (score -1):

> https://vigu-madurai.medium.com/solved-alternate-to-the-default-scrollintoview-8da76e083066

Creo que esto puede ayudarte..

Comment: Esta respuesta es más bien un comentario, dado que no resuelve directamente el problema basado en el código que ha dado el autor de la pregunta.